# query on powershell script that downloads the Microsoft Ebook Giveaway books

Tags: powershell

Got a whatsapp message that Microsoft is giving away free ebooks from the below url.

URL : [Microsoft Ebook Giveaway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mssmallbiz/2017/07/11/largest-free-microsoft-ebook-giveaway-im-giving-away-millions-of-free-microsoft-ebooks-again-including-windows-10-office-365-office-2016-power-bi-azure-windows-8-1-office-2013-sharepo/)

To download all the books in one go, the following powershell script was used, which is available in the same url.

Now my problem is, if I run the powershell script as a whole, it is not throwing any error. All the books from the url gets downloaded to a single location in my computer.

But if I try to run the script line by line to understand what each statement does, it is giving the following error when the , $bookList = Invoke-WebRequest $downLoadList gets executed,

Now to resolve this error, there are many others posts in stack overflow, that passes the username and password to overcome this error. Those scripts / solutions are not working at my end.

More than the error, why is it, that the script runs without any errors/issues when I execute the full script, but throws an error when I execute line by line ?

Any inputs on the nature of execution or helpful tips in overcoming the error will be useful... Thank you.

**Error :**

```
Invoke-WebRequest : (my ip number )
Credentials are missing.
Make sure to specify a domain with your username
This website has been blocked by a cyber security policy
and SecureWeb does not currently support web exceptions
If you have an exception, copy the link below into a new tab
http://ligman.me/2tk1D2V
At line:1 char:13
+ $bookList = Invoke-WebRequest $downLoadList
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) 
    [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
   InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**PowerShell Script :**

```
############################################################### 
# Eric Ligmans Amazing Free Microsoft eBook Giveaway 
# https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mssmallbiz/2017/07/11/largest-free-microsoft-ebook-giveaway-im-giving-away-millions-of-free-microsoft-ebooks-again-including-windows-10-office-365-office-2016-power-bi-azure-windows-8-1-office-2013-sharepo/
# Link to download list of eBooks 
# http://ligman.me/2tk1D2V
# Thanks David Crosby for the template (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/david%20crosby/)
#
# Modified by Robert Cain (http://arcanecode.me)
# Added code to check to see if a book was already downloaded,
# and if so was it the correct file size. If so, the book
# download is skipped. This allows users to simply rerun the
# script if their download process is interrupted. 
############################################################### 

# Set the folder where you want to save the books to
$dest = "I:\new_microsoft\" # Make sure the file path ends in a \

# Download the source list of books 
$downLoadList = "http://ligman.me/2tk1D2V" 
$bookList = Invoke-WebRequest $downLoadList 

# Convert the list to an array 
[string[]]$books = "" 
$books = $bookList.Content.Split("`n") 

# Remove the first line - it's not a book 
$books = $books[1..($books.Length -1)] 
$books # Here's the list 

# Get the total number of books we need to download
$bookCount = $($books).Count

# Set a simple counter to let the user know what book 
# number we're currently downloading
$currentBook = 0 

# As an option, we can have it log progress to a file
$log = $true

if ($log -eq $true)

{

  # Construct a log file name based on the date that
  # we can save progress to
  $dlStart = Get-Date
  $dlStartDate = "$($dlStart.Year)-$($dlStart.Month)-$($dlStart.Day)"
  $dlStartTime = "$($dlStart.Hour)-$($dlStart.Minute)-$($dlStart.Second)"
  $logFile = "$($dest)BookDlLog-$dlStartDate-$dlStartTime.txt"

}

# Download the books 
foreach ($book in $books) 

{ 

  # Increment current book number
  $currentBook++
  try

  {

    # Grab the header with the books full info
    $hdr = Invoke-WebRequest $book -Method Head 

    # Get the title of the book from the header then
    # make it a safe string (remove special characters)
    $title = $hdr.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[-1] 
    $title = [uri]::UnescapeDataString($title) 


    # Construct the path to save the file to
    $saveTo = $dest + $title 

    # If the file doesn't exist, download it
    if ($(Test-Path $saveTo) -eq $false)

    {

      $msg = "Downloading book $currentBook of $bookCount - $title"
      $msg
      if ($log -eq $true) { "`n$($msg)" | Add-Content $logFile }
      Invoke-WebRequest $book -OutFile $saveTo 

    }

    else

    { 

      # If it does exist, we need to make sure it wasn't
      # a partial download. If the file size on the server
      # and the file size on local disk don't match, 
      # redownload it

      # Get the size of the file from the download site
      $dlSize = $hdr.BaseResponse.ContentLength
      # Get the size of the file on disk
      $fileSize = $(Get-ChildItem $saveTo).Length

      if ($dlSize -ne $fileSize)

      {

        # If not equal we need to download the book again
        $msg = "Redownloading book $currentBook of $bookCount - $title"
        $msg
        if ($log -eq $true) { "`n$($msg)" | Add-Content $logFile }
        Invoke-WebRequest $book -OutFile $saveTo 

      }

      else

      {

        # Otherwise we have a good copy of the book, just
        # let the user know we're skipping it.
        $msg = "Book $currentBook of $bookCount ($title) already exists, skipping it"
        $msg
        if ($log -eq $true) { "`n$($msg)" | Add-Content $logFile }

      }

    }

  } # end try

  catch 

  {

    $msg = "There was an error downloading $title. You may wish to try to download this book manually." 
    Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor Red
    if ($log -eq $true) { "`n$($msg)" | Add-Content $logFile }

  } # end catch

} # end foreach 


# Let user know we're done, and give a happy little beep 
# in case they aren't looking at the screen.
#"Done downloading all books"
#[Console]::Beep(500,300)
```

Comment: @4c74356b41 when I execute the script line by line, and when I execute this line $bookList = Invoke-WebRequest $downLoadList

Comment: How are you executing it line by line? I threw it in the ISE and was able to walk through it and run `$bookList = Invoke-WebRequest $downLoadList` just fine and then play around with `$booklist`

Comment: @Sambardo going to the line and pressing F8. the lines with $dest and $downloadList are working fine with F8. Once I go to the line with $bookList and press F8, it throws up the error mentioned in the question. I executed it in the PowerShell ISE only. One more thing, I am doing this from my office environment, but still it is puzzling to see, the whole script runs without any issues, why is it that it is failing line by line.